# correlation matrix based on column that contain lists

Tags: r, vector, correlation

hi i have data that looks like this:
[image]

data  sample code:

```
df <- structure(
    list(
      Christensenellaceae = c(
        c(0.085476686, 0.012516773, 0.012998767),
        
         c(0.053681065, 0.043963266, 0.027482013),
        c(0.042259744, 0.017749, 0.022012028)

       ), 
      Treatment = c("Treatment 1","Treatment 10","Treatment 2"),class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-9L)
  )
```

as you can see each row is a vector of 3.
what i wish to do is to creat a  sperman correlation matrix between the treatments.
i tried :

```
cor(df,method = "spearman")
```

but got an error :

```
Error in cor(df, method = "spearman") : 'x' must be numeric
```

it should look like this:

[image]

is it beacuse the treatment column has strings ? if so how can i fix this ?

Comment: `cor(list2DF(df[[2]]), method = 'spearman')`

Comment: Your sample data gives an error.

Comment: @Onyambu is there any way to have thr treatment column so it would be possible to know which correlation is with that type of treatment ?

Comment: @maydin what type of error?

Comment: @ElizaR You can see if you run your data code on your R session. There is something missing in there.

Comment: @maydin  is there any way to fix the error and get whe correct result similar to the pic above?

Comment: `cor(data.frame(setNames(df[[2]],df[[1]])),method='spearman')`

Comment: @Onyambu it returns somthing weird:                           setNames.df..2....df..1...
setNames.df..2....df..1...                          1
>

Comment: Seems you have it different. Do setnames df[[1]], df[[2]] instead of df[[2]], df1[[1]]